# how to retrieve users data from firebase stored by there uid

Tags: javascript, html, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve data from firebase db using Html and js I'm not very good on web dev so this is my first web dev not quite familiar with it, so my users stored by there uid [here's  the data struct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mosr8.png)

her is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Side Navigation Bar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sidebarStyle.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b99e675b6e.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>name:</th>
                    <th>phone:</th>
                    <th>id:</th>
                </tr>
                <tbody id="table">

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-database.js"></script>


<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIza........",
    authDomain: "........",
    databaseURL: ".........",
    projectId: ".......",
    storageBucket: "........",
    messagingSenderId: ".......",
    appId: "1:.....:web:.......",
    measurementId: "G-......"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"  
integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="   
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="usersTable.js"></script>
        
 </body>
</html>
```

my Javascript code is in a separate file -> `usersTable.js` another problem is when I'm writing firebase no auto-completion appears I did install typescript, the code that I tried is following this guy instruction but didn't work for me https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nUUPedePJ4o
***if there is anything wrong with my code or I do have to install firebase tools or not let me know***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve data of signed-in user:

[Assuming that you want the details of the signed-in user]

```
// get current logged in user details
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

// get the branch of the user
const userBranch = firebase.database().ref('/users/'+user.uid);

// retrieve the data from that branch - Remember this is an asynchronous function - it returns promise
userBranch.once('value').then((snapShot)=>{
   var userPhoneNo = snapShot.val().phone;
   var userPic = snapShot.val().profileImageUrl;
   var userName = snapShot.val().username;
});
```

Resource: [Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once)

If you want to learn more about asynchronous functions - [Link](https://javascript.info/async-await)

About your second problem, there are no extensions available for autocomplete in JavaScript for Firebase.

Edit 1:

[Fetching all the users from users branch]

```
// this will get the whole user branch
const userBranch = firebase.database().ref('/users');

// retrieve the data from the database
userBranch.once('value').then((snapShot)=>{

 var userDetaills = snapShot.val()

 userDetails.forEach((user)=>{
  let userPhone = user.phone;
  let userPic = user.profileImageUrl;
  let userName = user.username;

  // your rest of the logic
 });
});
```

Comment: actually the firebase user sign-in on the mobile app so there is no current user sign from the website my website is like a dashboard that I want to display all the users in and I want to access there info inside there 'uid' like there username and email ect do you get me?

Comment: second thing on replying on how to get usersInfo by there uid here is what I got `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'user.uid')`

Comment: I have made the edit as required by you, the whole branch of the users be retrieved. And about the error `TypeError: null is ....` is because you have no user signed in for your dashboard. `currentUser` returns the details of the currently signed in user.